# Fetch html and image from URL in python: HTTP Error 403 or Cloudflare-protected page with captcha

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib, urllib3

I want to get html code from URL with python script. when I use 'urllib' library, It is works for many sites but in my specific URL case, I get 'HTTP Error 403: Forbidden'. Here is Example I having problem with it:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen, urlretrieve

url='https://bama.ir/car/detail-szx9y9u-hyundai-sonata-hybrid-gls-plus-2017'

header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
req = Request(url, headers=header)
web_byte = urlopen(req).read()
webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')
print(webpage)
```

Download Image directly with python script in this specific url has same error. Example of that:

```
link="https://cdn.bama.ir/uploads/BamaImages/VehicleCarImages/6d364e82-f39d-419a-b346-257014928907/CarImage9557638_2_thumb_900_600.jpeg"
name=link.rsplit("/",1)[1]
urlretrieve(link,name)
```

When I use 'BeautifulSoup' or 'cloudscraper' or 'urllib3' library, Cloudflare-protected page with captcha is received. Here Example of that:

```
url="https://bama.ir/car/detail-grxi644n-hyundai-genesis-coupe-2011"

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
soup = bs(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
print(soup.text)

import cloudscraper
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
print(scraper.get(url).text)

import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request("GET",url)
print(r.data)
```

When I use 'selenium' library, sometimes it is working but sometimes Cloudflare-protected page with captcha appearing. For downloading Image I just have to use screenshot function. Here Example of that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
url="https://cdn.bama.ir/uploads/BamaImages/VehicleCarImages/a36114cd-1978-41a4-a558-cbe5f652faf1/CarImage9473771_0_1_thumb_900_600.jpg"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
driver.close()
```

Comment: how did you fetch it ? show us the code

Comment: I think it depends on the web page you wanna fetch and not how you did it locally.